# jQuery - detect element top change

Tags: jquery

How can I detect when an element's top has changed?
For instance, on a div element.
my code like this:

```
$(selector).onchange("top",function()  
{  
  // ...
});
```

Comment: You can't. Your best bet would be to monitor the style change in a timer.

Comment: Well, why would the CSS top property change, or in other words, where are you changing it ?

Comment: What is causing the element's `top` to change? Could you not do what you need to do when that occurs?

Comment: Your question is not that much clear,
I think you are expecting for first child